# What's the best practice to run the same github python code on several ec2 instances?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, python-venv

I'm using venv for my python repo on github, and wanted to run the same code on 10+ ec2 instances (each instance will have a cronjob that just runs the same code on the same schedule)

Any recommendations on how to best achieve this + continue to make sure all instances get the latest release branches on github? I'd like to try and automate any configuration I need to do, so that I'm not doing this:

1. Create one ec2 instance, set up all the configurations I need, like download latest python version, etc. Then git clone, set up all the python packages I need using venv. Verify code works on this instance.
2. Repeat for remaining 10+ ec2 instances
3. Whenever someone releases a new master branch, I have to ssh into every ec2 instances, git pull to the correct branch, re-update any new configurations I need, repeat for all remaining 10+ ec2 instances.

Ideally I can just run some script that pushes everything that's needed to make the code work on all ec2 instances. I have little experience with this type of thing, but from reading around this is an approach I'm considering. Am I on the right track?:

- Create a script I run to ssh into all my ec2 instances and git clone/update to correct branch
- Use Docker to make sure all ec2 instances are set up properly so the python code works (Is this the right use-case for Docker?). Above script will run the necessary Docker commands
- Similar thing with using venv and reading the requirements.txt file so all ec2 instances has the right python packages and versions

Comment: How often do you change the number of ec2 instances? How often does the code run? How often does the code change?

Comment: Ah good points, the use case for this is a scraper running on 10+ machines, so outside traffic from users won’t be a factor. It’ll be running as much as possible, though realistically probably 10-20 hours a day. The number of ec2 instances will rarely change for now, can consider it as fixed. There won’t be any need for auto-scaling, as deciding when to add / remove instances to get more / less scraping done will be a manual call to make. Also no problem is it takes up to a few hours to get the new instance up and running. Code will change 2-3 times a week.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your app and requirements (is EC2 100% necessary?) I can recommend following:

1. Capistrano-like SSH deployments (https://github.com/dlapiduz/fabistrano) if your fleet is static and you need fast deployments. Not a best practice and not terribly secure, but you mentioned similar scheme in your post
2. Using AWS Image Builder (https://aws.amazon.com/image-builder/) or Packer (https://www.packer.io/) to build new release image and then replace old image with new in your EC2 autoscaling group
3. Build docker image of your app and use ECS or EKS to host it. I would recommend this approach if you're not married to running code directly on EC2 hosts.